# AngularJS Следующая картинка по щелчку

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="img in items" ng-init="currentIdx = 0;">
 <img ng-src="{{ img.listfile[currentIdx].filename }}" ng-click="currentIdx = currentIdx + 1;" height="250" width="250"/>
</div>
```

В items массив:

```
{name: "Ivan", number: "89269269696", listfile:Array(4)
0: {filename: "userivan1.jpg"}
1: {filename: "userivan2.jpg"}
2: {filename: "userivan3.jpg"}
3: {filename: "userivan4.jpg"}
}
{name: "Valeriy", number: "89209209090", listfile:Array(5)
0: {filename: "uservaleriy1.jpg"}
1: {filename: "uservaleriy2.jpg"}
2: {filename: "uservaleriy3.jpg"}
3: {filename: "uservaleriy4.jpg"}
4: {filename: "uservaleriy5.jpg"}
}
```

и т.д.
По клику на картинке, открывается следующая в массиве. Но после того, как currentIdx получает индекс последней картинки, изображения перестают меняться. Как можно выполнить переход по картинкам массива по кругу, а не до последнего элемента.

Comment: Например через функцию: ng-click="changeIndex(currentIdx)"
функцию естественно написать.

Comment: `ng-click="currentIdx = img.listfile.length === currentIdx ? 1 : (currentIdx + 1);"`, но лучше оформить обработчик функцией

Comment: Как раз с функцией то у меня и затруднения. Не пойму, как её оформить касательно ваших примеров.

Comment: `ng-click="currentIdx = (currentIdx + 1) % img.listfile.length;"`

Comment: Функция была бы удобнее. Буду признателен, если кто-нибудь скинет пример.